# Saving Children Entities in with Sequential Ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent entity who has 17 children entities. When I save them, the child IDs are generated randomly, not sequentially in the order that I put them in the collection.

Is there a way to restrict child entities to be in sequential orders?

Comment: First of all, why do you care about the order of IDs?

Comment: I read children from file and have to put them on screen like that they stay on file.

Comment: Then you shouldn't rely on ID values to order, create an order property.

Comment: Is there any other way that supported by entity framework?

Comment: You could probably hack it, but why? Making it explicit is much more sensible.

Comment: I have to change too much code with an order value and I have to finish asap. Maybe I could save children in order and call savechanges many time. There is 1 insert in this table for per 3 minutes, so there is no performance issue.

Comment: Like I said, you can probably hack it, but any shortcuts you take now are just going to give problems later on.

Comment: Seems like hacking is way more complicated than introducing a new column `Order` that you can just do Order++ when saving. What's so hard on that?

Comment: @AhmetArslan you've made an incorrect assumption, that there is some kind of order in the database. There isn't one. Even if the child entity ID in the database is an IDENTITY, sequential values aren't guaranteed. The *only* guarantee is that they are incrementing. Frankly, adding an `Row` field and incrementing it in a loop should be trivial. You shouldn't need to add more than 1-2 lines of code

Comment: @AhmetArslan as for `put them on screen like that they stay on file.` the only way to do that is to add an `OrderBy` call. Rows in a database have no implicit order and the server can return them in any order it likes. You'd need to add `OrderBy(x=>x.Id)` to get the entities sorted by ID anyway. You can change that to `.OrderBy(x=>x.Row)`

Comment: @DavidG and Panagiotis , I chose your recommended approach and it worked better and I impemented faster. Thanks you guys ;)